# DNS query re website Status: inactive

Tags: dns

There is a website that I am assisting with which, when you do a DNS look up on [Who.is](http://who.is), returns a Website Status of "inactive".  I also noticed the server type is incorrectly reported.

This is not a website I generally use for DNS queries so am unsure if it is reliable.  Using other DNS checking services reports what Iwould expect and the site is functioning correctly.

Research I have done with regard to **Website Status: inactive** suggests an issue with the DNS configuration?

I am looking for help understanding if this is something to be concerned with and if possible how to update this value or how it gets set in the first place.

Comment: When does who.is show the WHOIS info was updated? Do they show the correct WHOIS server and WHOIS/DNS info?

Comment: It is showing as updated in the last 6 hours. The WHOIS server and name servers look correct for the domain. This particular data falls out side of the REGISTRY information under 'site information' so I am unsure if they are connected in anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who.is or any other web information database generally is not instantly updated, so dont worry and check your self via cmd or terminal.

**If you are using windows :**

Open run dialog box
Type cmd

```
>ping domain.com
```

if the site response without error, no problem.

If you are recently changed any dns settings in your server
Type:

```
> flushdns
>ping domain.com
```

---

**If you are using mac**

type terminal and

```
> ping -c 1 domain.com
```

if the site response without error, no problem.

If you are recently changed any dns settings in your server
Type:

```
> dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
> ping -c 1 domain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data from the whois server of the registry is correct, then there is no need to worry.  Online tools such as who.is simply repeat this information.  If you are seeing bad information from them, but good information directly from the source, then it is the online tool that has the problem.